# Space $\mathcal{L}^p(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is separable iff $(\Sigma, \rho_\Delta)$ is separable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

**Let's** consider the space $\mathcal{L}^p(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ of all functions $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) for which:
$$
\int\limits_X|f|^p \mu(dx) < \infty.
$$
Here $X$ is a metric space, $\Sigma\subset 2^X$ — sigma-algebra on $X$ and $\mu$ — is the measure on $\Sigma$. As usual, functions that are equal almost everywhere considered to be equivalent, so technically we are dealing with classes $$[f]=\{g\in \mathcal{L}^\infty(X,\Sigma, \mu) \colon \mu \{x\in X\colon f(x)\neq g(x)\}=0\}.$$ This space is endowed with integral metric $$\rho_p(f,g)=\left(\int\limits_X|f-g|^p \mu(dx)\right)^{1/p}$$

**The statement is** that space $\mathcal{L}^p(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is separable iff $(\Sigma, \rho_\Delta)$ is separable, where $\forall A,B\in\Sigma$ $$\rho_\Delta(A,B)=\mu(A\Delta B)$$
Here, again, we consider $A\in \Sigma$ as a class $[A]=\{A'\in\Sigma\colon \mu(A\Delta A')=0\}$ to have the identity of indiscernibles.

How do one prove the statement?

Comment: This result is false. The implication "if $\mathcal{L}^p(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is separable then $(\Sigma, \rho_\Delta)$ is separable"  is false. Here is a counter-exemple: 

Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}},\mu )$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure. Since for any $A,B\in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, if $A\ne B$, $d_{\mu}\left(A,B\right)\geq1$ and $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable, it is clear that the measure space $(2^{\mathbb{N}},\rho_\Delta(\mu) )$ is not separable. On the other hand, as $L^{p}\left(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}},\mu \right)$ is $l^{p}$, and $l^{p}$ is separable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it has been pointed out by Ramiro, the assertion to be proved in the question is false. Only one of the implications is correct that is if $(\Sigma, \rho_{\Delta})$ is separable, then $L^p(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ is separable. This is what will be shown below.

Let $\chi_A$ be the characteristic function of the set $A$. Now observe that

$\| \chi_A - \chi_B\|_{L^p}^p = \int|\chi_A - \chi_B|^p = \int_{A\setminus B}1 + \int_{B\setminus A}1 = \mu(A\setminus B) + \mu(B\setminus A) = \rho_{\triangle}(A,B)$

Now consider the function $\varphi: \Sigma \to L^p(X, \Sigma,\mu )$ defined as $ A \mapsto \chi_A$.

This is an injective map from $(\Sigma, \rho_{\triangle})$ to $(L^p(X, \Sigma,\mu), \rho_p)$.

Observe that $\rho_{\triangle}(A_i,B) \rightarrow 0 \Leftrightarrow \|\chi_{A_i} - \chi_{B} \|_{L^p} \rightarrow 0$.

<strike>Consider a countable dense subset in $L^p$ say $f_i$. Now choose an element from each of the following sets $B(f_i,1/k)\cap \mathrm{Im}(\varphi)$ say $\chi_{A_{i,k}}$ where $i$ and $k$ vary over natural numbers. This will be a countable subset of $\mathrm{Im}(\varphi)$. For any given $\varepsilon$ and $\chi_A$ there exists $f_j$ such that $\| f_j - \chi_A \|_{L^p} < 1/k < \varepsilon/2$. Now let's choose $\chi_{A_{j,2k}}$, then $\| \chi_{A_{j,2k}} - \chi_A \|_{L^p} \leq \varepsilon $.</strike> Mistake in this argument was also pointed out by Glinka below.

Let $\lbrace A_i \rbrace$ to be a dense subset in $\Sigma$. Now consider the vector space spanned by $\mathbb{Q}\chi_{A_i}$. This is a countable set. This is dense in the vector space spanned by $\mathbb{R}\chi_{A_i}$ which is dense in $L^p$ since simple functions are dense in $L^p$. One can suitably modify the proof for complex valued functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Are you sure that characteristic functions are dense in $L^p$? Let $X$ be $[0,1]$ with standart Lebesgue measure and $p=1$. Consider function $f(x)=x$. The closest a characteristic function can get to $f$ is $1/2$, am I right?

Comment: You are right. I was being sloppy. One has to consider the the Q-vector space generated by the dense subset in $\Sigma$. That will do the job. The resulting space will still be countable. Is that ok?

Comment: The first step of your derivation only holds for $p=1$.

Comment: @PhoemueX, it holds for each $p$, since $1^p=1$ and $0^p = 0$, and $1$ and $0$ are all values that you can get by substracting two characteristic functions

Comment: Yes, but you have to take the whole shebang to the power $1/p $ if you want to get a metric. But I just noted that you also omitted that power in your question.

Comment: @PhoemueX, oh right...

Comment: @PhoemueX, "But I just noted that you also omitted that power in your question", yes, my bad, I always forget about it

Comment: What's $B(f_i, 1/k)$? What functions are in this set?

Comment: This is ball of radius 1/k in L^p with center at f_i.

Comment: Well the the intersection $B(f_i, 1/k)\cap \mathrm{Im}\varphi$ can be empty, right? I mean, for some $i, k$.

Comment: Yes it could be empty. But the proof works fine. I am only interested in the case when $\| f_j - \chi_{A}| < 1/k$. In that case $B(f_j,1/k) \cap image(\phi)$ is non empty. And there we have already chosen $\chi_{A_{j,k}}$ which could be equal to $\chi_A$. But the proof goes through?

Comment: This result is false. The implication "if $\mathcal{L}^p(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is separable then $(\Sigma, \rho_\Delta)$ is separable"  is false. Here is a counter-exemple: Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}},\mu )$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure. Since for any $A,B\in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, if $A\ne B$, $d_{\mu}\left(A,B\right)\geq1$ and $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable, it is clear that the measure space $(2^{\mathbb{N}},\rho_\Delta(\mu) )$ is not separable. On the other hand, as $L^{p}\left(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}},\mu \right)$ is $l^{p}$, and $l^{p}$ is separable.

Comment: @Ramiro You are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have made the necessary edits.

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement is that the space of summable functions (modulo a.e. equivalence) is separable if and only if there is a countable collection C of measurable sets of finite measure such that for each measurable set Q of FINITE measure and each integer N there is a set A in the collection C such that the measure of the symmetric difference between Q and A is less that 1/N. I have been unable to find a published proof of this statement, but the assertion is made in a book by Zaanen on measure theory published around 1967. However, the proof of the tricky direction made there is wrong. I know how to prove this result. If readers are interested I will provide a proof here.

Comment: May I ask why this answer has been deleted? It is mathematically correct, and this is all that counts here. The counterexample given by Ramiro is not a counterexample to the correct statement, that I have given, which is well known to experts in measure theory. Indeed, infinite subsets of the collection of natural integers have infinite measure. I am able to provide a proof of the correct statement. I find it strange that the ``reviewers'' have deleted my answer instead of asking for a proof.

Comment: Would you please give a proof?  I cann't find a published one.