# Proof of the separability of $L^p (X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ when $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I took a course on Measure and Integration last semester and this semester on Functional Analysis. In the problem sets we were given the fact (we should know from last year's course) that

> $L^p (X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is sepearable when $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Unfortunatly we did not prove this fact in the Measure and Integration course. Does anyone know the full proof of this? I would much appreciate if one could be detailed in proving it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Detailed proofs can be found in almost every book on functional analysis or measure theory but may be You can proof it on Your own with the hint below

Comment: could you recommend a book? I cannot seem to find it anywhere in our math library at uni.

Comment: It seems You´re right. I tried to look it up in several books and couldn´t find a proof either. I ´ll think about a detailed proof.

Comment: It seems to me that $\sigma$-finiteness is not enough. Maybe one should assume separability of $X$, but i cannot find a counterexample when $X$ is not separable.

Comment: And I just thought, that $\sigma$-finiteness may imply separability, i.e. that it might be stronger...

Comment: I´m  sure now You need the space $X$ to be separable and that this is not implied by the $\sigma$-finiteness

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The step functions are dense in $L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ ( or $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$).
Because of this and since $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite,i.e. $X$ is the countable union of sets of finite measure, there is a countable and dense set of stepfunctions with values in $\mathbb{Q}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: But it seems that separability of the measure space is required https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447055/space-mathcallpx-sigma-mu-is-separable-iff-sigma-rho-delta-i , isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I agree. $\sigma$-finiteness of the measure is not sufficient.