# counting measure space is not separable but the corresponding $L^p$ space is separable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$ be a measure space. We define a pseudometric on measure space: for any $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$ $$d_{\mu}\left(A,B\right)=\mu\left(A\Delta B\right)=\mu\left(\left(A\setminus B\right)\cup\left(B\setminus A\right)\right)$$
 $d_{\mu}$ becomes a metric if $\mathcal{F}$ is considered the equivalence relation $X\sim Y$ if and only if $d_{\mu}\left(X,Y\right)=0$ for any $X,Y\in\mathcal{F}$. The measure space $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$ is called separable measure space iff $\mathcal{F}$ is separable with respect to metric $d_{\mu}$. In other words, there exists a countable sequence $S$ of measurable sets in $\mathcal{F}$ , such that for all measurable sets $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $B\in S$ such that $d_{\mu}\left(A,B\right)<\epsilon$.

We have the conclusion that space $L^{p}\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)\left(1\le p<+\infty\right)$ is separable iff $\left(\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right),d_{\mu}\right)$ is separable.
See this [Space $\mathcal{L}^p(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is separable iff $(\Sigma, \rho_\Delta)$ is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447055/space-mathcallpx-sigma-mu-is-separable-iff-sigma-rho-delta-i).

Consider counting measure space, $X=\left\{ 1,2,\dots\right\}$  ,$\mathcal{F}=2^{X}$, $\mu\left(\left\{ x\right\} \right)=1$ for $x\in X$, we can see that for any $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$ and $A\ne B$, we have $d_{\mu}\left(A,B\right)\geq1$ and we know $\mathcal{F}$ is uncountable, so counting measure space $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$ is not separable.

On the other hand, as $L^{p}\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$ is $l^{p}$ space , and $l^{p}$ is separable as $X$ is countable, so $\left(\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right),d_{\mu}\right) $should be separable.

Can someone figure what's wrong here?

Comment: The statement "Space $\mathcal{L}^p(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is separable iff $(\Sigma, \rho_\Delta)$ is separable" is false.  In fact, it is not true that "If space $\mathcal{L}^p(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is separable then $(\Sigma, \rho_\Delta)$ is separable". You have just showed a counter-exemple.

Comment: Yeah, I just figure it out...If $\left(\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right),d_{\mu}\right)$ is separable, then $L^{p}\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)\left(1\le p<+\infty\right)$ is separable, but the reverse may not hold. Thanks!

Comment: Separability is a topological property, how can you conclude that $X$ is not separable after saying that there are uncoutablely many measurable sets? In fact, $X$ is separable, just because it is countable. And this is not a proper counter-example.@Ramiro @Leoalan.Huang

Answer (score 2):

Here is what is wrong: the correct statement is that the separability of $L^p$, $1\le p <\infty$, is equivalent to the existence of a countable collection $C$ of measurable sets of *finite* measure such that for each measurable set $Q$ of *finite* measure and for each positive $r$ there exists a set $A\in C$ such that the measure of $Q\Delta A$ is less that $r$. Hence, it is *not* the collection of all measurable sets but only the collection of measurable sets of *finite* measure that needs to be considered in the statement of separability on the side of sets.

The paper [Separability of the L1 space of a vector measure](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/glasgow-mathematical-journal/article/separability-of-the-l1space-of-a-vector-measure/CB35C4A6052D01D4B5C04049D2565A98) by Werner J. Ricker, published in the Glasgow Mathematical Journal in 1992 refers to this as a ''classical result'' and points to the book of A. C. Zaanen ''Integration'' published in 1967 for a proof. The proof given in this book is not convincing, but the result is true and I can provide a proof if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

The counting measure is separable.  A measure space is separable iff it is generated by a countable collection of sets, modulo completion.   In this case, the singletons generate the $\sigma$-algebra that is the power set.

Comment: However, I define $X$ to be countable here, may be the natural number set

Comment: How can you talk about separability of a measure space without specifying a topology?