# Separability of $L^p(\mathbb R^n ,\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure in $\mathbb R^n$ it is true that $L^p(\mathbb R^n,\mu)$ is separable?
I not find a proof of these fact, I only would know that these is true.

Comment: Maybe this could help? [Space $\mathcal{L}^p(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is separable iff $(\Sigma, \rho\_\Delta)$ is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1447100)

Comment: Yes, it is true. But the proof is rather long and not very interesting. Take the set of step functions with rational coefficients and use the radon property to implement an approximation procedure.

Comment: See for instance Theorem 22.15 of [*Analysis Tools with Examples* by Bruce Driver](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/DRIVER/Book/anal.pdf).  For the set algebra $\mathcal{A}$, fix any countable base $\mathcal{U}$ for the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra generated by $\mathcal{U}$, which you can verify is again countable.  So in fact, "Radon" can be relaxed to "$\sigma$-finite".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $1 \leq p < \infty$. Yes if you have a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ whose $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ is generated by a countable set $\mathcal{C}$, then $L^p(X, \mu)$ is separable. The proof for when $\mu$ is finite is simple: Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$. You can show that $\mathcal{A}$ is countable, and then using the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem or the monotone class theorem, you can show that closure of the set $\{1_A : A \in \mathcal{A} \}$ in $L^p$ contains $\{1_{E} : E \in \mathcal{F}\}$. Thus the span of this set over $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $L^p(X, \mu)$, proving separability.

You can easily reduce the $\sigma$-finite case to the finite case.